# Showing 20 rows at a time with postgresql

Tags: postgresql

I want to show 20 rows at a time and I also have a button that will show the next 20 rows if they exist in the table. I plan on populating the table strictly with sql queries so I want to be able to write a query that will show me the next 20 rows. This is my sql code I have so far

```
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE dodge AS 
 SELECT p.p_name, p.p_id, p.p_price, p.cid, u.u_name, st.name, s.quantity     
  FROM sales s JOIN products p ON s.pid = p.p_id JOIN users u ON s.uid = u.u_id 
   JOIN categories c ON p.cid = c.c_id 
   JOIN states st ON st.st_id = u.state;

SELECT * FROM dodge ORDER BY u_name LIMIT 20;
```

I know the select statement will give me the first 20 but how do I get the next 20 and so on?

Comment: you can play with `LIMIT` and `OFFSET`

Comment: It's called pagination. Use a cursor, or limit and offset.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By using the [OFFSET](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/queries-limit.html) keyword:

```
SELECT * FROM dodge ORDER BY u_name LIMIT 20 OFFSET 20;

SELECT * FROM dodge ORDER BY u_name LIMIT 20 OFFSET 40;
```

And so on!